# Get all but one properties of a javascript object without modifying it

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object like this:

```
let obj = {
    foo: "bar",
    baz: "quux",
    banana: "apple"
}
```

And i want another object containing all the properties in `obj` but one, something like

```
{
    foo: "bar",
    banana: "apple"
}
```

I don't want to change `obj`, so using `delete` is not an option, and i'd also like to avoid writing a function that loops on `Object.keys` and sets all properties but `baz` to a new object.

Is there a native function to do something like this, basically like a `slice` for objects?

Comment: You could use [*Object.assign*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.assign) to "copy" the object, then delete the unwanted property.

Comment: var clone = Object.assign({}, obj);
delete clone.baz;

Answer (score 1):

Assign to new object and delete unwanted

```js
let obj = {
    foo: "bar",
    baz: "quux",
    banana: "apple"
};

var clone = Object.assign({},obj);
delete clone.baz;

console.log(clone);
```

Comment: `delete` can be slow. [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null/16). Use it when you doesn't care about perf and you know what are you doing. [see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21735614/1248177)

Comment: thanks for the info @aloisdg

Comment: @aloisdg: Of course a re-assignment is going to be faster. `delete` also is the only method to properly ___remove___ a property from an object.

Comment: Also, that benchmark is [horribly outdated](http://jsben.ch/#/gu1Gi), @aloisdg.